# After running 'npx create-react-app todo --typescript' tsx files are not present

Tags: reactjs, tsx, react-tsx

I'm new to typescript, I read some react articles with typescript and saw the below command for installing the boiler plate with tsx files. When I ran it, I never get the tsx files are even tsconfig json. What am I missing

`npx create-react-app todo --typescript`

Comment: This is working for me fine though. What is your OS? and npm version?

Comment: @aitchkhan I'm using Mac

Answer (score 0):

Creating TypeScript App using cmd `npx create-react-app todo --typescript` (--typescript flag) is deprecate now we should use `npx create-react-app ts-app-name --template typescript`

Answer (score 0):

`npm install typescript --save-dev` and `npm install cra-template-typescript --save-dev` before running `npx create-next-app --ts` solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

npm install -g create-react-app
This may take a few minutes to install. You can now create a new React application by typing:
create-react-app my-app

TypeScript is now supported natively in Create React App. You can use the
--typescript option instead when generating your app to include TypeScript support. 
Would you like to continue using react-scripts-ts?

Running the project
Running the project is as simple as running
npm run start

Testing the project
Testing is also just a command away:
npm run test

Creating a production build
When running the project with npm run start, we didn't end up with an optimized build. 
Typically, we want the code we ship to users to be as fast and small as possible. 
Certain optimizations like minification can accomplish this, but often take more time. 
We call builds like this "production" builds (as opposed to development builds).
To run a production build, just run
npm run build

Comment: the question is about npx, why would you recommend global install?